# Eliminate timestamp timezone offset in lattice xyplot

Tags: r, timestamp, lattice

When using `lattice` to plot values against hourly timestamps, I've found there is an annoying timezone shift from UTC to local time in the graph's x-axis labels. Though this example uses `lubridate`, the issue occurs when using `POSIXct` directly. For example:

```
library(lattice)
library(lubridate)
foo <- data.frame(t = seq(ymd_hms("2015-01-01 00:00:00"),
                          ymd_hms("2015-01-02 00:00:00"), 
                          by = "hour"),
                  y = 1:25)
head(foo)
xyplot(y~t, foo) # time axis is behind by 5 hours (EST = UTC-5)
```

One solution is to specify the timezone explicitly:

```
tz(foo$t) <- ""  # or tz(foo$t) <- "EST"
head(foo)
xyplot(y~t, foo) # time axis now agrees
```

Are there other ways to get `lattice` to plot directly in UTC without modifying the timezone of the data? Perhaps using the `scales = list(x = list(format = ...))` argument? I can imagine situations where it would be bad to change the data's timezone, specifically when dealing with daylight saving events.

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach would be to temporarily overwrite your system's timezone with the timezone from your data, and reset it to its previous value once the plot has been created:

```r
tzn = Sys.getenv("TZ")
Sys.setenv(TZ = tz(foo$t))

xyplot(
  y ~ t
  , data = foo
)

Sys.setenv(TZ = tzn)
```

[image: xyplot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug; the process of combining per-panel limits into an overall limit (even if there's only one panel) loses attributes, including the tz attribute.

```
p <- xyplot(y ~ t, foo)
str(attributes(foo$t))
# List of 2
#  $ class: chr [1:2] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
#  $ tzone: chr "UTC"
str(attributes(p$x.limits))
# List of 1
#  $ class: chr [1:2] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Fixed by setting

```
attributes(p$x.limits)$tzone <- "UTC"
```

Other workarounds are

```
xyplot(y ~ t, foo, xlim = extendrange(foo$t))
xyplot(y ~ t, foo, scales = "free")
```